# How to fire dynamically created button click event inside TableRow?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

This is my code:

```
public class GolfExpoDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

RequestObject requestObject;
public static final String URL_EXPODETAIL ="http://knowledgeops.in/halogolf/upmeapi/class-woocommerce.php?function=search_golf_expo_api";
TextView expotitle,expodescription,stdate,endate,city;
ImageView imageView;
List<StallBO> stallBOList;
TableLayout tableLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_golf_expo_details);
   /* Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/
    expotitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expodetail_title);
    expodescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expodetail_description);
    stdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expodetail_sdate);
    endate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.expodetail_edate);
    city=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.expo_loc);
    tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_table);
    long stallId = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("stallId");

    try {
        requestObject = ExceptionRequest.generateSingleRequest("id", stallId);
        requestObject.setUrl(URL_EXPODETAIL);
        new ExpoDetailList().execute(requestObject);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




        }

private class ExpoDetailList extends AsyncTask<RequestObject, Void, JSONObject> {


    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(RequestObject... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(arg0[0], ServiceHandler.POST);

        //  List<Products> result = new ArrayList<Products>();

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        JSONObject expo = new JSONObject();


        if (jsonStr != null) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                expo = jsonObj.getJSONObject("rsBody");

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return expo;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        stallBOList= new ArrayList<StallBO>();
        try{
            String title = result.getString("eventName");
            String description = result.getString("description");
           // String price = result.getString("Price");
            String img = result.getString("photoUrl");
            long productId = result.getLong("id");
            String sdate = result.getString("eventDate");
            String edate = result.getString("eventLastDate");
            String loc = result.getString("eventLocation");
           // String quantity = result.getString("quantity");
            //Integer length = result.getInt("length");
           // Integer width = result.getInt("width");
            JSONArray products = new JSONArray();
            products = result.getJSONArray("stallInformation");
            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                stallBOList.add(convertDetails(products.getJSONObject(i)));
            }



            expotitle.setText(title);
            expodescription.setText(description);
            stdate.setText(sdate);
            endate.setText(edate);
           // productPrice.setText("Rs" +Double.toString(price));
            Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(GolfExpoDetails.this);
            Picasso picasso = builder.build();
            picasso.load(img)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_plusone_tall_off_client)
                    .resize(100,100)
                    .into(imageView);
            city.setText(loc);

            for (StallBO stallBO:stallBOList)
            {
                View tableRow = LayoutInflater.from(GolfExpoDetails.this).inflate(R.layout.table_expo,null,false);
                TextView stall_size  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_stall_size);
                TextView price  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_stall_price);
                TextView stall_Quantity  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_sqty);
                EditText user_Quantity  = (EditText) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_qty);
                Button add_cart  = (Button) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.add_cart);

                stall_size.setText(String.valueOf(stallBO.getWidth())+"*"+String.valueOf(stallBO.getHeight()));

                price.setText(stallBO.getPrice());
                stall_Quantity.setText(String.valueOf(stallBO.getQuantity()));

                tableLayout.addView(tableRow);

            }

        }
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return;

    }

    private StallBO convertDetails(JSONObject obj) throws JSONException {
        Integer width = obj.getInt("width");
        Integer height = obj.getInt("height");
        Integer quantity = obj.getInt("quantity");
        String price = obj.getString("price");


        return new StallBO(width, height, quantity, price);
    }

}
}
```

My .xml file for TableRow is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="#2877AC">

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/expo_stall_size"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/expo_stall_price"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/expo_sqty"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/expo_qty"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/add_cart"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</TableRow>
```

My question is, where would I write a onClickListener for the button which is inside the for loop and how would I send the data of that row to the server when that button is clicked.

Comment: You can set on click listener to add_cart button. like below `add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
......
            });`

Comment: whhich dynamic button are you taking about??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onClickListener` will be created in for each row that is added to the table:

```
   for (StallBO stallBO:stallBOList){
        View tableRow = LayoutInflater.from(GolfExpoDetails.this).inflate(R.layout.table_expo,null,false);
        TextView stall_size  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_stall_size);
        TextView price  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_stall_price);
        TextView stall_Quantity  = (TextView) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_sqty);
        EditText user_Quantity  = (EditText) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.expo_qty);
        Button add_cart  = (Button) tableRow.findViewById(R.id.add_cart);


        //Here is where you will set the onClickListener:
        add_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                <the code of what needs to be sent to your "server">
            }
        });

        stall_size.setText(String.valueOf(stallBO.getWidth())+"*"+String.valueOf(stallBO.getHeight()));

        price.setText(stallBO.getPrice());
        stall_Quantity.setText(String.valueOf(stallBO.getQuantity()));

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
```

Comment: But sir my Question is Still there,How can i get tableRow data inside click listener of that row button?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it the following way, `dynamicallyCreatedButton.PerformClick()` which forcefully causes the button to be clicked.